# How to find all read Only Storage in Android devices?

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-permissions, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I apologize for my bad English grammar.

I want to know whether android devices have both read only and read/write storage in same device ?

If yes, how to get readOnly Storage directory.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Using this code can be retrieve the path of primary storage device.

Actually I want  to do, get all directories of internal and external storage and check whether those are ready only or read/write separately..

Is it possible to find all directories and check whether writable ?

Answer (score 1):

If the SD Card is readable, You can retrieve all files and folders in a simple way:

```
String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then easily get a list of files with:

```
File sdFile = new File(sdPath);
File fileList[] = sdFile.listFiles();
```

After getting the list, You can check wether a file is readable, writable or both. Also if it is a file or directory, if it is a directory, go on and search this directory also for readable/writable files. Little example:

```
for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++){

   File fileListFile = fileList[i];
   boolean isReadable = fileListFile.canRead();
   boolean isWritable = fileListFile.canWrite();
   boolean isDir = fileListFile.isDirectory();

}
```

It´s only an example which should lead You into the right direction. There is more to do, if You want to list the readable/writable files or directories.

Comment: thanks for your help. but it returns only files in sdcard0.. how can i get all files in sub folders also

Comment: If I am understand You the right way, use getFilesDir() instead of getExternalStorageDirectory()..